# Rails - Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed from EC2 instance to external Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm connecting from a Rails App to an external database using 
`Net::SSH::Gateway.new('hostname', 'username')` in order to create a tunnel for the localhost.

If I run the app locally, I can connect perfectly and access the external database, but when I do it on a EC2 instance, I get an `Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed`on that same line.

The weird part is that if I log into my EC2 instance through ssh and then I access the external server through ssh in the EC2 console, I can successfully connect. What could it be that I can't connect through the rails app?

Comment: Do you have outbound rules defined in the Security Group assigned to the EC2 instance?

Comment: I have "All Traffic" for testing purposes.